# Unable to create a management zone in dynatrace using uri module ansible

Tags: ansible, dynatrace

I am having hard time to create a management zone in dynatrace using ansible playbook on rhel 7 below is my code, and expected output and actual output

```
uri:
        url: "https://{{ xxxxxxx }}/e/{{ xxxxxxx }}/api/config/v1/managementZones"
        method: POST
        return_content: yes
        validate_certs: no
        status_code: 201,400
        headers:
           Accept: 'application/json'
           Authorization: 'Api-Token {{ xxxxxxxx }}'
        body_format: json
        body: "{{ somejsonoutput }}"
      register: managzone
      run_once: true
```

I am expecting above code to create management zone if it is not available but it is not working as it is expected.

expected output:

```
dynatrace_response_source": "Cluster",
        "elapsed": 0,
        "failed": false,
        "frame_options": "xxxxxxx",
        "json": {
            id: "xxxxx"
            name: "xxxxx"
                    }
            }
        },
        "msg": "HTTP Error 400: Bad Request",
        "pragma": "no-cache",
        "redirected": false,
        "status": 400,
```

but below is actual output

Output

```
"dynatrace_response_source": "Cluster",
        "elapsed": 0,
        "failed": false,
        "frame_options": "xxxxxxx",
        "json": {
            "error": {
                "code": 400,
                "constraintViolations": [
                    {
                        "location": null,
                        "message": "must not be blank",
                        "parameterLocation": "PAYLOAD_BODY",
                        "path": "name"
                    }
                ],
                "message": "Constraints violated."
            }
        },
        "msg": "HTTP Error 400: Bad Request",
        "pragma": "no-cache",
        "redirected": false,
        "status": 400,
```

Comment: Can you run it with "-vv" to get debug-output, maybe there is some more information visible there.

Comment: I quickly tried it and you get the HTTP 400 when the ManagementZone already exists. To update you need to use PUT instead of POST. So you would need to query for existing ManagementZones first and perform POST or PUT respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing one of parametrs in payload body(json format) or your stucture of json is invalid. Check it in [documentation](https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/dynatrace-api/configuration-api/management-zones-api/post-mz/#tabgroup--request-parameters).
One of the required is the name of the MZ, other parameters is optional.
Try to create MZ without rules first.